# Magento - Tax Excluded on Product Details Page but Included on Listing Page

Tags: magento

My problem is that I don't have the same price in Product Details and Listing Page.

I want to have all over the website the prices Included Tax.

How Can I solve this problem probably of configuration in Magento backend.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Most of these settings can be adjusted in _System->Configuration->Sales/Tax->Calculation settings_

Comment: Actually, there is only an option to include/exclude/both in Catalog - not both product listings / views. Bizzboss, are you using a custom there? There might be a problem in the .phtml files regarding the tax calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for Product List :
look at the following file
root/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

you will see the following code which you can change what you want :

```
    <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 0)): // including ?>
        <span class="price-excluding-tax">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $_taxHelper->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
            <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price+$_weeeTaxAmount,true,false) ?>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="price-including-tax">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $_taxHelper->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
            <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax+$_weeeTaxAmount,true,false) ?>
            </span>
        </span>
    <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)): // incl. + weee ?>
        <span class="price-excluding-tax">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $_taxHelper->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
            <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price+$_weeeTaxAmount,true,false) ?>
            </span>
        </span>
```

Comment: Your suggestion works but the code their looks like the feature should be built in and picked up automatically based on Magento price settings in the backend?